# How to extract third column from C array?

Tags: c

I have array defined like this

```
float array [1000][3]
```

I want to extract third column

```
float third[1000]
for (i = 0; i < 999,i++)
```

and then what?

Comment: Is what you want `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) third[i] = array[i][2];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    third[i]=array[i][2]; 
}
```

This should do it if I understood your question correctly.